# Ruby on Rails: Why does my array set contain null, passing my null checker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a code that looks like this:

```
*movie_requests is a scope

def self.records (producer_id = 0)
  actor_list = Array.new
  movie_requests(producer_id).find_each do |studio|
    actor = studio.actors.pluck(:id).uniq
    if (!actor_list.include? actor) && (!actor.nil?)
      actor_list << actor
    end
  end
  return actor_list
end
```

Originally in the database, it has these actor ids:

```
[[12305], [3749], [1263], [], [], [1263], [], [12305], []]
```

.pluck and .uniq makes redundant ids from each studio distinct however `[]` still exists:

```
[[12305], [3749], [1263], []]
```

Why doesn't my `&& (!actor.nil?)` condition catches the null ids and make it a distinct object?

> Edit:  `return actor_list.compact` also doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check `actor` is present or not and then add this `actor` in `actor_list`

and why is your `!actor.nil?` here is the reason:

```
actor = []
actor.nil? #gives you false
!actor.nil? #gives you true
```

and also `!actor_list.include? actor` also gives you true
so your both conditions are true and because of this it entering in if condition and appending [] to your `actor_list`

you can do something like these:

```
def self.records (producer_id = 0)
  actor_list = Array.new
  movie_requests(producer_id).find_each do |studio|
    actor = studio.actors.pluck(:id).uniq
    if actor.present? && (!actor_list.include? actor)
      actor_list << actor
    end
  end
  return actor_list
end
```

Then you will not get any blank array like this one [].

Comment: thank you! i didn't know that there is such as `.present`. Really just a new programmer in ruby. I also missed that condition